# Using HierarcicalDataTemplates in conjunction with TreeViewItem control templates

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate, itemspanel

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to template the following TreeView item layout:

[image: TreeView Item Layout Mockup]

I have several items, SearchList, which contains a collection of Search, which contains a collection of DataSet (sort of, but that is beside the point).  What I am having difficulty with is styling each node level the way I want.  I am using MVVM, and the TreeViews ItemsSource property is set to an ObservableCollection of SearchListViewModels which in turn contain my objects all the way down the object tree.

I can successfully style the SearchList HierarchicalDataTemplate to display them correctly.  Where I get hung up is on SearchTerm nodes styling.  I want the DataSets to be represented in a wrap panel or uniform grid (I haven't decided yet) to the right of the SearchTerm content area.  I have modified a TreeViewItem control template to behave this way I think), however if I set it in the ItemContainerStyle property of the Search HierarchicalDataTemplate, it does nothing.  All that gets displayed is the content for the Search.

## My Altered TreeViewItem Template

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="AlteredTreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                            MinWidth="19" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.414*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.586*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Background="#7F058956">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Margin="10,0" />
                    </Border>
                    <WrapPanel x:Name="ItemsHost"
                        Grid.Column="2" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## My Search Hierarchical Data Template

```xaml
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SearchViewModel}"  ItemsSource="{Binding MySearch.Custodians}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlteredTreeViewItem}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MySearch.SearchName}" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Surely it is possible to both style differently *and* have child items laid out differently? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are pretty close to what you're after. I tried to recreate your scenario based on the code you posted and I noted some problems with it *(which of course are based on my interpretation of the code you posted)*

- You are missing the `ContentSource="Header"` part of the `ContentPresenter`
- I think you are applying the `ItemContainerStyle` at the wrong `HierarchicalDataTemplate` level. It should be specified on the parent in order to affect the children (in your case `SearchListViewModel`).
- The default `Template` for `TreeViewItem` lays out the `ContentPresenter` in an `Auto` sized `ColumnDefinition` so the `WrapPanel` won't succesfully wrap unless you modify the `ItemContainerStyle` for the parent as well. *I changed it to a `UniformGrid` in my sample below*

With the changes from above and a few other things I got a result that looks like this which hopefully is pretty close to what you're after

[image]

I uploaded the sample solution here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4v2t8imikkagueb/TreeViewAltered.zip?dl=0

And here is the Xaml code for it *(too much code to post it all..)*

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- DataSet-->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:DataSet}">
        <Border BorderThickness="3"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tables[0].TableName}"
                       Margin="5"/>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- SearchViewModel -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SearchViewModel}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DataSets}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   FontFamily="Arial"
                   FontSize="16"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <!-- SearchListViewModel -->
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SearchListViewModel}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SearchList}">
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.414*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.586*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                        Background="#7F058956">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <UniformGrid x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                             Grid.Column="2"
                                             Columns="3"
                                             IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"
                   FontSize="20"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchListViewModels}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That looks great!  I will take a gander at it in the morning.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank Meleak for a great solution.  It worked as advertised and showed me the error of my ways.  With only a little more styling I now have an eye-pleasing way to visualize a large hierarchy of data in a much more compact space.  Enjoy the extra rep!

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Sure thing, glad I was to able :)

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Are you looking for any additional info to award the bounty? Just checking since your previous comment indicated that you planned to award it and it's ending tomorrow :)

Comment: I apologize.  I thought marking it as the answer would award the bounty, but that is not so.  All done.  Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Great solution! One thing I would do is make a new `UserControl` as the content of the `<ControlTemplate .../>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Something I learnt a long time ago when trying to create a *similar* interface was that  you are **better** using a `ListBox` than a `TreeView`.

Why?

1. If you only have one level of expansion (as it appears from your sample) you will a lot more control of the layout as you have a single `DataTemplate` to style.
2. It is lot easier to customize a `ListBox` than a `TreeView` as you do not have be concerned with the `GridViewColumnHeader` and `GridViewColumnPresenters` etc.

To get the expansion part (which is why you initially selected a `TreeView`), simply use a `Grid` with two rows defined and an `Expander` in the second row bound to the `IsChecked` property of a `ToggleButton`. See the example that I pulled from my *Log Viewer*.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,3" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" SharedSizeGroup="SSG_TimeIcon"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" SharedSizeGroup="SSG_Time"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" SharedSizeGroup="SSG_LevelIcon"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" SharedSizeGroup="SSG_Level"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="SSG_Message"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- ProgramTime -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignme="Top"  HorizoalAlignme="Stretch" Fill="{StaticResource Icon_Timer}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignme="Top" HorizoalAlignme="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=TimeStamp, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToStringConverter}}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=ProgramTime}"/>
        <!-- Level -->
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignme="Top" HorizoalAlignme="Stretch" Fill="{Binding Path=Level, Converter={StaticResource MappingConverterNinjaLogLevelEnumToBrushResource}}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=LevelFriendlyName}" VerticalAlignme="Top" HorizoalAlignme="Stretch"/>
        <!-- Message -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" Orieation="Horizoal" >
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=LogMessage}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignme="Top"  HorizoalAlignme="Stretch"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpandExceptiooggleButton" VerticalAlignme="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsChecked="False" 
                          Coe="Show Details" Tag="Hide Details" Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}"
                          Foreground="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" Background="{StaticResource RedBrush}"
                          Visibility="{Binding Path=HasException, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElemeName=ExpandExceptiooggleButton}" Style="{StaticResource CoeExpanderStyle}" 
                  Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkGreyBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">                                
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Exception}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </Border>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Can you see how much easier it is to define a header and expandable body. If you do have a need for nested data, add a Level property your view model (you are using MVVM aren't you?!) and then create a `IValueConverter` that returns a Margin (i.e. `Thickness`) to fake the indent.

Comment: Yeah, I had hoped to be able to use the TreeView though, as I am expecting soon to have a requirement to layout items in a fairly long hierarchy and a listbox will no longer be viable, methinks.  I know that it works great for items in three levels of hierarchy, but for items in 20 levels?  I am hoping to layout the upcoming required view in a true tree (items branching out from parents) and it seems like TreeView would be best as it is specifically designed to host hierarchically arranged items like that.

Comment: I would *still* continue to use a `ListBox` **unless** I actually needed columns. I have created a file manager (to display assets in our game editor/tools) using the 'fake'  indent approach which had to be able to display 20,000+ items (obviously using virtualization) that could be *n* levels deep (where *n* is the max. folder nesting allowed on NTFS drive). It does hold up *very* well.

Comment: I generally agree.  I have used ListBox before in this manner.  My only real problem with using ListBox over TreeView in matter like this and my upcoming requirement is that TreeView (however disfunctional it is at the moment) is made for this purpose while ListBox can be "tricked" into it.  It still works and all.  This is just an attempt to use these items which were designed for this express purpose.  I have +1ed for the good suggestion and code samples.